# Drop every even or odd frames using FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, framerate

Is there an accurate way to take raw video and extract from it a new video that contains only odd frames or even frames (by choice)?

For example:

I have "blah.yuv" with 400 frames (0-399).
I want to create "blahOdd.yuv" that contains frames 1-399 (1,3,5,7...399)
and "blahEven" that contains frames 0-398 (0,2,4,6...398).

Any ideas how to do it using only FFmpeg?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To work accurately, first convert the video to RAW YUV bitstream (if it is not already) by:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -an -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p rawbitstream.yuv
```

Next step: The [`select` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) takes [an expression](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation), where `n` is the frame number.

```
ffmpeg -r 2 -s WxH -i rawbitstream.yuv -filter:v select="mod(n-1\,2)" \
-c:v rawvideo -r 1 -format rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -an odd.yuv

ffmpeg -r 2 -s WxH -i rawbitstream.yuv -filter:v select="not(mod(n-1\,2))" \
-c:v rawvideo -r 1 -format rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -an even.yuv
```

To have `ffmpeg` not duplicate frames, you have to force half of the framerate of your input - so you set "2" as the input and "1" to the output. Don't forget to replace the WxH with the actual dimensions of your clip because the raw bitstream doesn't have a header that carries this information.

Instead of the above, another possibility would be to add the [`setpts`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#asetpts_002c-setpts) filter to set new timestamps for the output. But be careful since it drops frames not accurately. Here, 25 is the actual output frame rate you want:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v select="mod(n-1\,2)",setpts="N/(25*TB)" \
-c:v rawvideo -r 12.5 -format rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -an odd.yuv

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v select="not(mod(n-1\,2))",setpts="N/(25*TB)" \
-c:v rawvideo -r 12.5 -format rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -an even.yuv
```

---

You can of course choose another pixel format (any of `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`). Make sure that when reading the file you know the pixel size and pixel format:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s:v 1280x720 -pix_fmt yuv420p input.yuv …
```

Comment: Thanks,
For new versions of FFMPEG it should be -vf instead of -filter:v. In addition it should be mod(n-1\,2) because the n count seems to start from from 1 while frame count from 0 (otherwise the first frame is duplicated 3 time).
But there is still a problem, it duplicates the frames while I want to get rid of them - e.g. the final clip will contain only half of the frames.

Comment: `-vf` is an alias of `-filter:v`. I can't reliably test it now, but will look into this later when I'm back on my machine. Maybe the [`tinterlace` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tinterlace) can do the same?

Comment: I've tried '-r 2 -i blah.yuv -r 1' but it shows me an error _Option framerate not found._

Comment: Ah sorry.. Scratch that, this doesn't work (anymore?) and only for images.

Comment: I think I figured out why. If you use the `select` filter to drop frames, `ffmpeg` will still try to create a video with the original input framerate, thus doubling the frames. Try specifying half the frame rate, or using the `setpts` filter.

Comment: The ‘setpts="N/(25*TB)”’ gives me weird frame count. For instance (even): 2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 16, 20, 22 ... (no 8, 14, 18). However I’ve found another way based on the ‘mod(n-1\,2)’. First, in case of compressed file, decode it to raw YUV: ‘-i input.mp4 -an -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p output.yuv’. With YUVs, input frame rate required, so it also works in this case :) So the second iteration will be ‘-r 2 -s WxH -i output.yuv -vf "select=mod(n-1\,2)" -r 1 -an -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p outputEven.yuv’. If the file is already YUV, only the second is needed. Works like a charm :)

Comment: @Mark I'd be happy for you to suggest an [edit] to my answer and add the steps that worked for you, thereby correcting any mistakes I made. You can also post your own answer and mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Great, thanks! Very interesting the way it works, I'm new to this system of Q&A :)

Comment: Can it not be done using the options `-framerate`/`-r` ?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi No, this just drops frames, but I wouldn't be sure that it's so deterministic (i.e., drops every odd frame). It'll be based on time codes, which may not be accurate.

Comment: Question: why YUV? Why is GBRP for example suboptimal?

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff YUV is a very efficient way to encode video because you can usually drop the resolution of the color components (U, V) and keep a higher resolution in the black-and-white portion (Y), because humans are better at identifying detail there (see "chroma subsampling"). The OP's question was about a .yuv file, too, so no need to convert between formats.

Answer (score 3):

If your ffmpeg was built with the AviSynth flag, then [I believe](http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-read-DirectShow-files_003f) you can pass an `.avs` file.

You can check by running `ffmpeg` and looking for `--enable-avisynth` in the **configuration** data.
[image: --enable-avisynth]

If it's there you can use it like so: `ffmpeg -i blahEven.avs blahEven.yuv`.

Where `blahEven.avs` is simply:

> ffvideosource("blah.yuv").SelectEven()

For odd frames, use `SelectOdd()`.

For more advanded usage, see the [SelectEvery](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Select#SelectEvery) documentation.

Comment: This is an excellent alternative, but as I've mentioned - I'm limited to use only ffmpeg. The reason for that is it is a part of an automated system that will create only .bat files, no possibility for addition AVS.

Comment: @Mark I was thinking that if `--enable-avisynth` was there, that it meant AviSynth was built into ffmpeg, but I'm not sure about that.